# get good url out of $_get with multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, get

I'm working on a search function but i have a problem getting an good url.

i'm starting on this page:

```
/product

product = index.php?page=product
```

After posting the form it looks like this:

```
/product?collectie=heren&searchleft=searchleft
```

so if i want to call the parameter searchleft it don't works because of de ? after product. So my goal is to get:

```
product&collectie=heren&searchleft=searchleft
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

my .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hello, How did you created the rewrite url method ? It's a custom .htaccess or a framework ? If it's custom, you just need to add a flag to pass QSA parameters :) https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Comment: Please post the rewrite rules of your server config (`.htaccess`).